# Error rendering variable in @click function call

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass an object property into a click event. I know you cannot pass curly brackets into html attributes since I have the title property output correctly. But how to do the same when trying to render a click event?

```
<p class="control" v-for="range in ranges">
    <a class="button is-outlined is-primary has-text-black" :title="range.title" @click="getNumber({{ range.id }})">{{ range.title }}</a>
</p>

invalid expression: expected property name, got '{' in

    getNumber({{ range.id }})

  Raw expression: @click="getNumber({{ range.id }})"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add key in v-for... And  @click="getNumber({{range.id}})" to @click="getNumber(range.id)"

```
<p class="control" v-for="(range, key) in ranges" :key="key">
        <a class="button is-outlined is-primary has-text-black" :title="range.title" @click="getNumber( range.id )">{{ range.title }}</a>
    </p>

    methods: {
    getValueNumber(value){
    console.log(value)
    }
    }
```

Comment: While your change to getNumber() was accurate, adding the key index gave me a warning: `Property or method "key" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

Answer (score 1):

```
getNumber(`${ range.id }`)
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Your solution also worked as I'm new to Vue so I attempt each different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please change @click="getNumber({{ range.id }})" to @click="getNumber(range.id )". Vue had compile it when variable in function.